# What rownum=-1 means in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I am not providing url in jqGrid and populating locally through jQuery an JSON objects.
What rownum=-1 means in jqGrid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `rowNum` have to be positive. If you need to display all the rows on one page you should just use large enough value for `rowNum`, for example `rowNum: 10000` or `rowNum: 100000`.

If you need you can change the text displayed in `rowList` for the largest value like it do the code below

```js
$("#list").jqGrid({
    ...
    pager: "pager",
    rowNum: 1000,
    rowList: [10, 25, 100, 1000, 5000],
    ...
});

// change the text "5000" to "All"
// the value of the option still be unchanged 5000
$("#pager option[value=5000]").text("All");
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I was looking at someone else's code where they have used rownum=-1, and that grid is showing one record less. I just want to confirm whether this may be the reason behind that.

Comment: @user2021698: Many people posted feature requests to support grid without paging `rowNum: -1`, but till now Tony (the developer of jqGrid) don't wanted to implement the feature. So you really have to use `rowNum` with some large enough value.